# ATTASK/WORKFRONT - API - This "is not a top level object"

Tags: api, attask

This sample will give me ALL the GUIDs for HOURS (Yes over 2000 you need to page to get the rest)
htps://YOURCOMAPNY.attask.com/attask/api/v4.0/hour/search?$$LIMIT=2000&fields=ID:*

Object=Hour
field=ID:* (wildcard for all)

If I wanted to do the same thing to SCANS (ScoreCard Answer)
htps://YOURCOMAPNY.attask.com/attask/api/v4.0/scans/search?$$LIMIT=2000&fields=ID:*

Object=scans (Scorecard Answer)
Field=ID:* (Wildcard All)

I get an error:

{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"SCANS is not a top level object and can't be requested directly in internal"}}

I Can do this to pull a ton of project information and I have to parse it all such as produced by this code.

htps://YOURCOMAPNY.attask.com/attask/api/v4.0/proj/search?fields=alignmentScoreCard:*,alignmentValues:*,alignmentValues:scoreCardQuestion:*

And if I click thru it I can find a ID for a scans and a scoreq and if I take that scans or scoreq and attempt to pull it using the field=ID or

htps://YOURCOMPANY.attask.com/attask/api/v4.0/scans/YOURGUIDHEREXXXXXXXXX/

This again tells me:
{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"SCANS is not a top level object and can't be requested directly in internal"}}

I can pull just about anything and get a list of ID's and then manually pull those items by ID but the scores/scorecard answers/scorecard questions (Even as the API seems to indicate that I can pull this like anything else does NOT allow me to do so?

Suggestions? I know its all associated with projectIDs and such I just want to get a list of them all and work with the ones that I want on a one - one basis without having to pull the PROJ and then rummage thru to locate all the ID's associated with it (If there are one or many) Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any workaround for this..
you have to go via projects only..
I am also searching a method for this...
I had to update scorecard answers and I had to go via projects..